# How to write a correct and effective introductory letter to an attorney?

Tags: attorney-fees

Is the following a well-done example of a letter to a lawyer making an initial (or telephone or zoom-meeting follow-up inquiry about the lawyer taking a case?

{name}

Would your law firm have an interest in reviewing the extensive evidence
we  - identity - have in hand, in light of the possibility of initiating
lucrative legal action against an Ohio business - identity - under Chapter
2741 of the Ohio Revised Code (ORC) comprising sections 2741.01 thru
2741.99. Particularly relevant are 2741.02, 2741.06, and 2741.07.

Will you kindly provide me with an opportunity to present our evidence?

We will be genuinely grateful if you come to see that we are authentic

traditional jewelry-making craftswomen who have been grievously wronged.

Our hope is to redeem the good name of our cooperative in the market

of humanitarian fashion vs. businesses counterfeiting our identity.

We only want to be in our home workshops alongside our families earning

a life of dignity as an jewelry-making artisan, so nobody needs to migrate.

To accomplish this, we find ourselves forced to learn how to sue an

ex-customer using the images of our families for commercial purposes.

This bad practice seems to closely fit the letter of the cited law.

If this suit suceeds, it could become very lucrative for the lawyers.

If you give me a chance to explain, I'll show you what I mean by this.

Please allow me to provide you with what you want to know about our case.

Attentively,

{name of the President and legal representative of Cooperative}

Comment: Why are you telling a lawyer the law ? I’m not an attorney but this letter marks you as a client who thinks they know it all.

Comment: I am telling the attorney what law we want to sue under.

Comment: @George White
 I have edited it to make the question clear.. Maria Alaniz
 If I have misunderstood you, please edit further or comment.

Comment: I hope I am doing this right.

Comment: If I go to a doctor and say: I have all the symptoms of malaria according to common knowledge and wikipedia; my neighbors were hospitalized for malaria recently, so I suspect I may have malaria, would this be considered disrespectful to the doctor?

Answer (score 7):

I think you would do much better to describe the situation, and the result you wish to achieve. Include enough detail for the lawyer to understand the nature of the case, but keep it **brief**. More details should come once the lawyer has agreed to take the case, or to give you an interview/consultation to discuss it.

Later in your letter, if you like, you might include "We understand that ORC  2741.02, 2741.06, and 2741.07 may give us a basis for suit" but I would not go into any more detail about the law in an initial letter.

If during the consultation (in person or by phone or zoom or some such), the lawyer does not mention laws you have learned of and think relevant, you could mention them and ask why the lawyer is not addressing them.

The lawyer does not need or want to be told what you think the law is, the lawyer needs to know what the situation is and what you hope to do about it. That includes who "we" are.

**Update**

As the answer from ohwilleke says, a telephone all might be better than a letter. But in either case, the key things the lawyer will need to know are: 1) who are you?; 2) what is the situation you are concerned with (details may be important here)?; 3) what do you want to accomplish through the lawyer's services?; 4) who are the other parties involved? You will want to learn: Does the lawyer m(olr law firm) handle that sort of case?; Are they willing to take you on as clients?; 3) Hpw much experience has this lawyer had with this sort of case?; 4) What are the likely upfront costs?; and 5) What are the chances of success?  Items 4 and 5 may not get answers in a first round of contacts.

**2nd update, based on revised letter**

You still start with a statement of the law you think give you a claim. Please do not do that. In this draft letter you do not say anything about  the actual problem you have or what you want done until the sixth and next to last paragraph of the letter. Even then you are not very clear on what you want the lawyer to do. "we find ourselves forced to **learn** how to sue an ex-customer" sounds as if you are asking for education, not legal services.

I would suggest something more like:

> We are an association of traditional artisans. An Ohio business {insert business name} that had formerly purchased and resold some of our work has been using the images of us and our families to advertise its goods without permission. We want this stopped and also want monetary damages for past use.

> We think we may have a claim under {ORC sections}. In any case we want this stopped by whatever legal process would be most appropriate.

That puts the situation first, your desire second, and any comment about the law later (or it could be left out).

Comment: I will make another attempt to compose a model letter for introduction to legal firm.

Comment: "That includes who "we" are." Also, a good lawyer should always want to know who "them" is to screen for conflicts of interest.

Comment: Yes of course you are right. In the actual letter, I will fill in the names of these principles.

Comment: I don't get it; if the lawyer needs to know so much information, why is the contact preferably by telephone? when a letter can better convey everything you have mentioned.

Comment: A letter may work. The advantage of a telephone or in-person contact is that it makes a back-and-forth exchange by which the lawyer can refine the details of the the problem from the initial client statement easier and quicker. It also makes possible a back-and-forth in which the client refines questions into the lawyer's experience and what the lawyer can and will do, at what cost and with what chance of success. Also, ohwilleke (who is a practicing lawyer as I am not) says initial phone or in-person contacts are more common and less likely to be dismissed by the law office.

Comment: @ahwilleke What do you want to hear from the phone-caller in the first 60 seconds after you have picked up?

Comment: @Maria Alaniz
 perhaps something like the suggested 2 paragraphs in my 2nd update formatted as a block quote.

Comment: @ David Siegel Thank you for that suggestion. Seems reasonable. I find it hard to fathom why cold-calling legal firms is the recommended method instead of explaining in a letter.

Comment: @David Siegel I probably have above-average phone skills, still cold-calling legal offices seems like such a crap shoot. Especially when we want to take legal action according to the letter of the law as written. If all lawyers are like the commentators here, I suspect they would be reluctant to even listen to something that is unusual or unfamiliar.

Comment: @MariaAlaniz and could you be more right! And the “commentators” are probably the people who will give you the most undivided attention you will get unless you start your call with your fat cash offer. You can forget the contingency and similar type of stuff where you have good reason to believe your case is in not a boilerplate and is in a niche.

Comment: @kisspuska Thank you. I have appreciated the lack of sympathy on the part of the commentators. Indeed, our case is in a niche, far from boilerplate, and fits the letter of the law like a glove.

Comment: @MariaAlaniz one thing you seem to have missed: You will not get half the attention and sympathy going through a screening or talking over the phone or in email with a firm or a lawyer that you get from the people here.

Comment: @kisspuska I don't doubt it! I was only referencing the advice I thought was bad or absurd. I have already learned that anything from Mexico automatically is sent to spam.

Comment: @kisspuska I have already learned that anything from Mexico is ignored. I was thinking of the recommendation to cold-call legal offices, to start off by telling a story that the other party would be unlikely to understand. I have to believe it better to present a letter outlining the case, including footnotes and hyperlinks as relevant. PLEASE Nobody take offense. All replies are appreciated.. The advice to cold-call struck me as unrealisitic. Again, sorry. Thanks to all for all responses.

Comment: @Maria Alaniz No offense taken. You must do as you see fit. At least two of those who suggested cold calling are working lawyers, i belive. If you do writ a letter, I suggest **not** including a "fat cash offer", as doing so will make your letter resemble the many scam approached lawyers seem to get. You can't know what  a suit would yield, so you can't know what a lawyer could reasonably get out of such a suit.  Any lawyer you want would know that.

Comment: Before asking here, I spoke with lawyers in Columbus and  in Fort Lauderdale Florida.  Both were unnecessarily rude and pointedly uninterested in learning any details of our case, or what it might entail. I felt that I had done a good job on each of those phone contacts, but that cold-calling lawyers is not a likely prospect to accomplish anything . BTW in the "Ask a Lawyer" forum I discovered before coming here, every one of the respondents was excessively offensive and pointedly uninterested in me or in helping me in any way. By comparison, Stacks features very high-quality contributors.

Answer (score 7):

It would be unusual to make an initial inquiry to an attorney by letter. There is too much give and take required at that stage and a phone call or an initial meeting in person would be much more common.

Fairly, or unfairly, at least half, if not more, of initial inquiries made to attorneys in a letter are either sophisticated versions of the [Nigerian prince scam](https://www.cnbc.com/2019/04/18/nigerian-prince-scams-still-rake-in-over-700000-dollars-a-year.html), or are from people who have no case and are a bit nuts. It is a similar phenomena to people not answering their phone in the face of calls from an unknown caller because it is so often a junk call.

I would not recommend proceeding to make initial contact with a lawyer in this fashion. If it helps you to prepare an outline of things you want to remember to talk about when you talk on the phone, or in a first, in person meeting, that is fine. But the effort that goes into writing a letter isn't worth it.

Comment: Thank you. I should think that on a random phone call, one would be speaking to a screener. What should be the first 20 words that one says to him or her? Wouldn't these words, and the way they are spoken, be crucial? ...to be allowed to speak to the attorney.

Comment: @MariaAlaniz Don't try to impress the lawyer with the law you know. The sample letter is awful. Stick to the facts. "Someone used our photographs of us to sell their goods without our consent, without payment, and over our objections, and are earning millions of dollars a year of sales with this ads. FACTS, FACTS, FACTS. Is this the kind of case that this office handles? If not, who would you recommend?" Often the answer will be "no". "We do routine landlord-tenant and foreclosure cases," or "commercial debt collection." A few times, it might be yes.

Comment: Thank you for your assistance; it is appreciated. I believe it is an obscure law that fits the case. For this reason, I doubt that attornies in Ohio would be familiar with it.

Comment: @Maria Alaniz
 Actually that law is not particularly obscure, and I had no problem finding it with a google search. any lawyer in Ohio would be likely to know of its existence in general terms even if that lawyer does not work on such cases or know all the details. Certainly if a lawyer works on personality or privacy cases s/he will know that law quite well.

Comment: A commenter has maintained that Lanham Act legislation is almost exclusively used for trademark wars; that the original purpose of it was to protect the public from misrepresentation and identity fraud.

Comment: I fear that an average Ohio lawyer would NOT necesarily know about the letter of the law nor the intent of the law as it is written; might not a modern lawyer think this law is only good for trademark combat?

Comment: @MariaAlaniz You aren't looking for an "average lawyer" you are looking for a lawyer whose practice includes this area of law. An average specialist in intellectual property or competition law probably would be familiar with it, and even if the lawyer wasn't, lawyers consider cases based upon facts and are wary of clients who focus on the law rather than the facts at the outset.

Comment: @ohwilleke We do have ample well-organized evidence (facts) however, it would be quite challenging (to me, at least) to present it in only a few words. For example, take the word "artisan"; Sometimes I have gotten the idea that many modern people do not know it's meaning. If someone has only a vague or a mistaken idea as to what the term "artisan" means, further explanations would be like talking to a piece of wood.

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not a good example of an introductory letter to an attorney.

A letter is generally going to be an ineffective way of reaching out to an attorney, and this one is not any better.

When I read this, red flags go up because the potential client appears to be placing herself in the role of the lawyer, by assessing the evidence, by choosing which legal claims to pursue, by explaining the law, by assessing the value of the case, etc. When a client comes in like this, I have serious doubt about the reliability of a "promise to be good clients."

Essentially none of the information in this letter will be valuable to an attorney.

Instead, an introductory letter should actually introduce you and your problem. It should provide a brief timeline of relevant facts and an inquiry as to whether they give rise to any kind of legal claims that the lawyer would be interested in pursuing. That's all you need.

Even then, though, letters are going to just seem weird to a lot of lawyers, who are accustomed to interacting with potential clients by phone. In my experience, letters usually come from prisoners or insane people. I would not be surprised if most lawyers you sent a letter to just ignored it -- even if it were very well written.

If you want to find a lawyer, you are probably a lot better off reaching out by phone, although it will take a lot more time.

Comment: Are phone skills as important to connecting with an attorney as you have made them seem? Wow. I never imagined that a telephone talk would be better than a letter.

Comment: All right, as a potential client of the legal firm, I get through to an attorney or a screener.
What would be the first 25 words to say? Also the first 50 or 100 words if allowed to talk.

Comment: A very brief explanation of your case. Something like, "I'm part of a collective of artists in Mexico, and an Ohio-based business has been using our names/likenesses/whatever to sell its products. We don't think they should be able to do that without our consent. Is this the kind of case you handle? Are there any attorneys you can recommend who do handle this kind of case?"

Comment: Thank you for this suggested introduction to a phone contact. Do you know of a way to determine what lawyers might have experience or interest in such a case before calling up all the divorce and auto crash lawyers, lawyers who only deal with tradmark disputes, criminal lawyers, worker benefit lawyers, and all the other kinds of lawyers out there? This would save the attorney answering a telephone call irrelevant to his or her practice and it would save the potential Claimant having to look for a needle in a haystack.

Comment: You could Google the law in question. If you find law firms writing about it, there's a chance that those firms are taking those types of cases. You could also call the bar association for the city where the defendant operates and ask for some referrals.

Comment: My understanding, derived from a comment in this thread, is that consumer protection from fraud is no longer the purpose of the law in practice, rather it is employed in trademark wars. I suspect that this observation may be accurate becasue of a legal article I found in my research written in 1999, referencing another legal article written 50 years previously, only 2 years after the Lanham Act was enacted,. These articles both lamented the diminishment of the law's original purpose: to protect the public from misrepresentation in favor of government involvement in purely commercial disputes.